# Wrapper of Business Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Following this 2010 article : [MVVM: To Wrap or Not to Wrap?](http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap-should-viewmodels-wrap.aspx)

I was wondering if since then it exists some kind of framework or class to help us build wrapper around Model object that would do all the plumbing regarding INotifyPropertyChanged model properties and ObservableCollection in model.

My point is I have to build an UI and have no control over the Model. The Model update itself and its different ObservableCollection and has numerous hierarchical levels.
Something like:

```
class A
      |
      some properties that implement INotify
      ObservableCollection<Class B>

class B
      |
      some properties that implement INotify
      ObservableCollection<Class C>

class C
      |
      etc...
```

Currently, the VM use direct reference to model properties but the UI is really simple.
A convenient way to be able to add the new UI features would be to have a VM per Model so I can add some custom UI properties in each level of the hierarchy and end-up with ObservableCollection of VM objects.

Before starting adding all this *painful plumbing* by myself which may cause me trouble and time, I wanted to check how people here are dealing with this.

Many Thanks .

Comment: There is, but you can't use it, because it depends on internals that you cannot access.  It is the ModelItem from WF4.  It is used in the designer to wrap POCOs and provide support for property change notification, collection change events, undo/redo, attached properties, etc.  If you study how it works, you can create your own implementation.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I'll go with the following:

[MVVM Wrapper](http://mvvmwrapper.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a number of things:

Use PostSharp to postprocess your compiled code to change the IL by adding the necessary code. Pros: quite easy. Cons: The line numbers in stack traces no longer match the line numbers in your source code. Personally, I don't use it for this.

Suck it up and write the code.

Myself, I use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) with a script like this:

```
void Main()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string source = @"        public bool Passed { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Type TestType { get; set; }
        public Exception Exception { get; set; }
        public TestStage StageFailed { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeTest { get; set; }";
    string[] lines = source.Replace('\r', ' ').Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string prop = lines[i].Trim();
        string[] propBits = prop.Split(' ');
        string type = propBits[1];
        string name = propBits[2];
        sb.Append("private " + type + " " + PascalCase(name) + ";\r\n");
        sb.Append("public " + type + " " + name + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("{\r\n");
        sb.Append("get { return this." + PascalCase(name) + "; }\r\n");
        sb.Append("set\r\n");
        sb.Append("{\r\n");
        sb.Append("if (this." + PascalCase(name) + " != value)\r\n");
        sb.Append("{\r\n");
        sb.Append("this." + PascalCase(name) + " = value;\r\n");
        sb.Append("RaisePropertyChanged(\"" + name + "\");\r\n");
        sb.Append("}\r\n");
        sb.Append("}\r\n");     
        sb.Append("}\r\n");     
    }
    sb.ToString().Dump();
}

private string PascalCase(string name)
{
    return name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + name.Substring(1);
}
```

I copy the code to put the INotify bits into it: `string source = @"` and the copy the output from running it back into my source code. Job done.

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a very, very useful tool.

Comment: Yaknow... if you didn't throw all those newlines in, the line numbers would still match...

Comment: They will still match as I do this in the source before compilation. It's the IL that PostSharp interweaves which changes the line numbers. This isn't using PostSharp.

Comment: Thank you for this. Having a look at PostSharp it seems very useful but I found this thread on the forum saying that it doesnt support for ObservableCollections: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/246-observablecollection-best-practices

Comment: As I said, I don't use it myself. Really, have a go at LinqPad; it's free.